# Fusionar duas tabelas numa terceira tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso fazer a fusão de duas tabelas `imagem1` e `imagem2` numa terceira tabela `imagens` com ***SQL***. Elas possuem exatamente a mesma estrutura mas com 1 consulta eu não posso escrever todos os dados de uma vez, então preciso fazer 2 consultas.

Preciso de um ***SQL*** para fusionar as tabelas numa terceira chamada `imagens`. O ponto de partida é o mostrado na imagem, não posso fazer nada de diferente antes desse ponto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas tabelas têm essa estrutura ....

- ID
- IMOVEL
- CODIGO
- IMAGEM_G
- IMAGEM_p

Em `imagem1` não tem os dados de **IMAGEM_G** enquanto que em `imagem2` não tem **IMOVEL** e **CODIGO**.

Na terceira chamada `imagens` preciso de todas estas informações juntas.

Comment: O `id` em ambas as tabelas corresponde à mesma imagem?

Comment: Sim, os IDs em ambas tabelas correspondem ao mesmo registro.

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que a correspondência entre as tabelas é pela coluna ID, não entendi por que precisaria de duas consultas. Eu faria assim:

```
INSERT INTO imagens
(id, imovel, codigo, imagem_g, imagem_p)
SELECT 
    imagem1.id,
    imagem1.imovel,
    imagem1.codigo,
    imagem2.imagem_g,
    NULL -- Se tiver imagem_p em imagem2, coloque aqui
FROM imagem1
    INNER JOIN imagem2
    ON imagem2.id = imagem1.id
```

Comment: Tentei o código da **Atualização** mas não executou nem deu erro. Tentei direto no phpmyadmin. Pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

Comment: Ah, vi agora que você editou o comentário. Não deu erro nem executou? Algum retorno ele dá, mesmo que seja *0 rows affected*.

Comment: Parece que ele congestiona o banco e não vai nem pra frente nem pra trás com o `INSERT`. E se eu fizesse update na tabela `imagem1` pegando somente a coluna **IMAGEM_G** da tabela `imagem2`. Resolveria meu problema!!! Como posso fazer?

Comment: A consulta do @bfavaretto está correta, porém dependendo do tamanho das tabelas, pode realmente travar o phpmyadmin. Tente executá-la usando o terminal diretamente, pode resolver pois não tem restrições de tempo de execução.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode apenas atualizar uma das tabelas como o exemplo abaixo, claro que apos atualizar sua estrutura.

```
UPDATE docs 
 INNER JOIN docs_1 
   ON docs_1.id=docs.id
SET docs.teste2=docs_1.teste;
```